# Excel VBA: How to fix an If Else For Loop error

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first vba project so please be patient.  I have created an Excel Userform to add info to a database.  When I click "add" I have vba script that should find the first open worksheet for that year (ex. Name_2018_1, Name_2018_2, Name_2018_3) or create a new consecutively named worksheet.

I keep receiving Compile Errors based on where I place my "then" and "exit for" statements.

I want the counter to either find the first worksheet with an available row or loop all the way through i and then make a new sheet based on the i value.

How do I correctly set up a for loop after my else?  If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong it would be appreciated.

```
'Dim myFirstBlankRow As Long
'Dim i               As Long
'Dim WsName          As String
'Dim WsNamei         As String
'Dim ws              As Worksheet
'Dim counter         As Integer

'Declare worksheet names
WsName = "Name_" & Year(Me.DTPicker1.value) & "*" 
WsNamei = "Name_" & Year(Me.DTPicker1.value) & "_" & i

For Each ws In Sheets
    If ws.Name = WsName Or ws.Name Like WsName & "*" Then i = i + 1
Next

'If no worksheet exists, then make a new one, else loop through until an empty row is found

If i = 0 Then 'No worksheet with the year selected by DTPicker
    With Sheets("Template")
        .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Add new worksheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = WsName & "_1"
    End With
```

*If I place the "Then Exit For" on one line I receive a Compile Error "Else without If"

```
Else:
    For counter = 1 To i Step 1
        Worksheets(WsName & "_" & counter).Activate
        If IsEmpty(Range("A1048576").value) = True Then Exit For
    Next counter


Else 'No recognizing the original If statement
    With Sheets("Template")
        .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Add worksheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = WsName & "_" & i
    End With
End If
```

*However, when I place the "Then" & "Exit For" on separate lines I receive a Compile Error"Next without For"

```
Else:
    For counter = 1 To i Step 1
        Worksheets(WsName & "_" & counter).Activate
        If IsEmpty(Range("A1048576").value) = True Then
        Exit For
    Next counter

Else
    With Sheets("Template")
        .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Add worksheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = WsName & "_" & i
    End With
End If
```

'Added for my modifications
I want the code to (1st) check for an original worksheet and make one if there is not. (2nd) If that original worksheet exists but is full, I want to make sure there is not already a new worksheet.  If there is it becomes the active sheet. (3rd) if there is not another available worksheet I need the script to make one.

I was originally having issues with a new worksheet being created and only one entry being applied to that worksheet prior to another worksheet being created, hence the 3 steps.

Should I split off the first If and then have the last 2 as their own entity for if the first worksheet is full?

```
If i = 0 Then 'No worksheet with the year selected by DTPicker
    With Sheets("Template")
        .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Add worksheet
        i = 1
        ActiveSheet.Name = WsName & "_" & i
    End With
ElseIf
    For counter = 1 To i Step 1
        Worksheets(WsName & "_" & counter).Activate
        If IsEmpty(Range("A1048576").value) = True Then
        Exit For
        End If
    Next counter
Else
    With Sheets("Template")
        .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Add worksheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = WsName & "_" & i
    End With
End If
```

Comment: That `Else:` should be `ElseIf` - you have 2 `Else`s in your `If` statement.

Comment: You can't do `If / Else / Else / Else / ... / End If`. You need `If / ElseIf / ElseIf / End If`.  So for your final `Else`, when would that trigger?  If `i <> 0`?  or is that the second `Else`, and you want to fire that final one regardless what `i` is?

Comment: This seems like a perfect opportunity to use `Select Case` instead of `If` when there are multiple conditions.

Answer (score 3):

If `Then` isn't followed by a statement, say, like this:

```
If IsEmpty(Range("A1048576").value) Then Exit For
```

Then it's the *block syntax* and since it's a block, it needs to be closed, in this case with `End If`:

```
If IsEmpty(Range("A1048576").value) Then
    Exit For
End If
```

That's why you get "next without for", because then without the `End If`, the compiler encounters `Next` before it gets to any `End If`, so the `For counter` loop block is considered not terminated.

Next problem, you can't have an `If...Else...End If` block with more than 1 `Else`.

```
Else:
    For counter = 1 To i Step 1
        Worksheets(WsName & "_" & counter).Activate
        If IsEmpty(Range("A1048576").value) = True Then Exit For
    Next counter


Else 'No recognizing the original If statement
```

VBA can't parse this; I can't parse this either. I've no idea what you intended to do here. If `i` is `0` you execute something, otherwise you execute something else - all bases are covered, an additional "else" just doesn't fit anywhere.

This would a template to work with:

```
If {bool-expression} Then
    {statements}
ElseIf {bool-expression} Then
    {statements}
Else
    {statements}
End If
```

The `Else` token identifies the "fallback" case. Having two makes no sense. Note that the instruction separator token `:` is redundant in `Else:`, and makes it look like a line label: avoid that.

---

### How to avoid this

When you type an `If` statement, *type the corresponding `End If` immediately*:

```
If something Then
    'type here
End If
```

When you later nest things, keep immediately closing whatever blocks you open:

```
If something Then
    For i = 0 To 10
        'type here now
    Next
Else
    'get back here later
End If
```

If things start being too hard to follow, grab the entire block and pull it into its own private procedure, passing whatever parameters are needed.

Answer (score 2):

## Next without For translates to missing End If

In the first case the `Else:` should be replaced with `Else` and the second `Else` should be removed.

In the second case you additionally are missing an `End If`, regardless of the Error.
The `End If` should be below the `Exit For` (above `Next Counter`).

They are equivalent, you are just using two different ways of the `If` statement.

### Case 1

```
If i = 0 Then 'No worksheet with the year selected by DTPicker
    With Sheets("Template")
        .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Add new worksheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = WsName & "_1"
    End With
  Else
    For counter = 1 To i Step 1
        Worksheets(WsName & "_" & counter).Activate
        If IsEmpty(Range("A1048576").value) Then Exit For
    Next counter
    With Sheets("Template")
        .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Add worksheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = WsName & "_" & i
    End With
End If
```

### Case 2

```
If i = 0 Then 'No worksheet with the year selected by DTPicker
    With Sheets("Template")
        .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Add new worksheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = WsName & "_1"
    End With
  Else
    For counter = 1 To i Step 1
        Worksheets(WsName & "_" & counter).Activate
        If IsEmpty(Range("A1048576").value) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next counter
    With Sheets("Template")
        .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Add worksheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = WsName & "_" & i
    End With
End If
```

Comment: `ElseIf` with what condition though?

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: Have you thought about what the code even does? This counting is pretty suspicious. Shouldn't the last 'i' be 'counter'?

Comment: TBH I haven't looked in any level of details, just the control flow outline - nice edit there, +1

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: Me too until now. Nice 'If' lecture.